# Subscribing to characteristics of peripheral

Tags: ios, ios7, xamarin.ios, core-bluetooth, ios-bluetooth

I am having issues with the return value from the peripheral for specific characteristic. What I am doing is- I have two characteristic types (notify and indicate). I subscribe to these characteristic using `peripheral.SetNotify(true,characteristic);` but the issue is device is not returning any value back. I am listening for values in did update value for characteristic method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to setNotify the characteristic value by using LightBlue or BLE Diag Tool iOS application.Then you can cross-check wheather it is problem on Peripheral side or on iOS App side?

Comment: Thanks, I will test the peripheral with LightBlue.

Comment: Light Blue helped understand the peripheral well.